# having trouble wrapping <a> tag around <li> in firefox 3.6

Tags: css

```
<a href="#vantage_model_home" class="model_link"><li id="vantage_btn">Vantage</li></a>
```

css:

```
    #model_nav li{float:left; display:block; position:relative; z-index:500; cursor: pointer; width:100px; height:37px; text-align: center;}

a.model_link{font-family: Helvetica;  color: #333333; font-size: 18px; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: none;   border:1px solid;}

a.model_link:hover{color: #aaaaaa;}
```

above is an example of one of my buttons in a list. what I want is a 100px by 37px li button that would invariably increase the size of the  tag to 100px by 37px. It works in safari and chrome, but in firefox the  tag only wrap around the text inside the li and not the li width and height.

Comment: Think about it... are you trying to build a list of links or a link of lists? Keep your HTML valid and put the links inside the list items.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTML doesn't allow `<a>` to be wrapped around `<li>` (None of the possible parent elements for `<li>` may have `<a>` as a child element, and `<a>` may not have `<li>` as a child element).

Put the links inside the list items, then style them as desired. It sounds like you want to start with `display: block`. [Listamatic](http://css.maxdesign.com.au/listamatic/) may provide further inspiration.